# How to add element to list Double programatically in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, double

I have syntax:

```
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
x.add(new double[] { 5,6,7,8 });
```

How to add 5,6,7,8 automatically? like this

```
for (int i=5; i<=8; i++) {
**CODE**
}

List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
x.add(new double[] { **CODE** });
```

So, I want to replace `**CODE**`, what is that `**CODE**`? is it possible? Sorry bad English

Comment: If my answer worked for you dont hesitate to accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double[] d = new double[4];
for (int i=5; i<=8; i++) {
    d[i-5] = i; 
}

List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
x.add(d);
```

Didnt test but should work if u wanna add a Array to an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Replace double with Double in your code. Like this:

```
List<Double> x = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i=5; i<=8; i++) {
   x.add(new Double((double)i));
}
```